# Passing an Arraylist of Java objects to a servlet from Java program

Tags: servlets, call

I would like to pass an arrayList of objects to a servlet from a java program.
Can some one please tell me, how this can be done.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this link they describe the process ind detail
http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/java/archives/0309/darby/index.html

Please note that if you are going to serialize objects back and forth that the compiled version must be in sync on both the client and the server or you will get errors.  I would recommend converting your objects to either XML or JSON and then reading them from that on the server side. That way if you client and server code get out of sync it will still work.

For the client I would recommend Apache's HttpClient (or whatever they have renamed it to)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a web service framework for this instead of coding a naked servlet? The whole business might be about 10 lines of code using, for example, an [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) JAX-RS service and client. If the objects are complex, you might want to use a full SOAP service.